# Obtaining remote host name in bash script

Tags: bash, hostname

Sorry my knowledge of Linux bash commands is pretty basic, I've been searching for a while but I'm not 100% sure what I need to search for.

I was wondering if there's a way to grab the current logged in users remote host name in a Linux bash script? I have a script in which I need to log each time a user runs it. I'm obtaining the date like so:

```
cdat=`/bin/date +%a' '%d' '%h' '%Y', '%H':'%M`;
```

I now need to add the users remote host (not the username they logged in with). I'm not 100% sure I'm using the right terminology here either, just to clarify; by 'remote host name' I mean the same output that prints on the screen on most servers I've logged into over ssh, for example:

```
Last login: Mon Jul 22 16:35:09 2013 from win7-i7-stuart.my.domain.com
```

I'm looking for the `win7-i7-stuart.my.domain.com` bit.

Comment: hit `set` to see environment, maybe `$SSH_CLIENT` is what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use the command `who am i` so that you don't get the duplicate info and have to parse it when using just a plain `who`.

```
$ who am i
sam      pts/6        2013-07-22 13:21 (192.168.1.110)
```

Humourously you can also use this:

```
$ who mom likes
sam      pts/6        2013-07-22 13:21 (192.168.1.110)
```

You can parse it using `sed` so that it's just the host they're connecting from:

```
$ who am i | sed 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/'
192.168.1.110
```

You can also see the entire history of a user's logins using the `last` command:

```
$ last <username>
```

For example:

```
$ last sam | less
sam      pts/6        192.168.1.110    Mon Jul 22 13:21   still logged in   
sam      pts/6        192.168.1.110    Mon Jul 22 11:02 - 11:02  (00:00)    
sam      pts/5        192.168.1.110    Thu Jul 18 14:41 - 16:41  (01:59)    
sam      pts/5        192.168.1.110    Wed Jul 17 15:56 - 16:28  (00:31)    
sam      pts/5        192.168.1.110    Wed Jul 17 15:56 - 15:56  (00:00)    
sam      pts/4        192.168.1.110    Wed Jul 17 14:28 - 14:29  (00:00)    
sam      pts/7        192.168.1.110    Tue Jul 16 16:27 - 16:50  (00:23)
```

#### References

- [4 Ways to Identify Who is Logged-In on Your Linux System](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/4-ways-to-identify-who-is-logged-in-on-your-linux-system/)
- [last man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last)
- [w man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/w)

Comment: You can also use `who a a`, or better yet, `who -m`, which is what is implied by having any two arguments.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - good to know. Thanks for the extra details.

Comment: Perfect, this works a treat, thanks for the reading material too :)

Answer (score 4):

```
who
jmcnama    pts/4        Jul 18 13:30    (9010-b6m2cx1.nmgco.com)
```

The last field of the who output  provides:

```
username=jmcnama
remote=$(who | awk -v user=$username '$1 == user {print $(NF)}')
```

There can be other problems, like the user is logged on multiple times.  The last command
can help as well.  last has problem - it can truncate long source node values.

As far as I know there is no /proc "file" that shows the origin of the login.  Last and who data are stored in /var//log/wtmp (usually).  So this is the only file source for this information.